# Apache Shiro userRolesQuery only looking for an int

Tags: java, security, authorization, shiro

I was able to authenticate using Apache Shiro, but now I need to authorize which means grabbing the roles from the database. The queries work, but only if I use roles that are integers. For some reason it is looking for roles to be integers. That seems unhelpful if I have to look for numbers as roles, am I missing some setting that tells Shiro to look for a string or varchar?

Here is my Shiro.ini file:

```
[main]
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory 
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
ds.resourceName = jdbc/SQL05

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT company_password FROM CompanyUser where company_username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role FROM CompanyUser where company_username = ?
```

Authentication.java

```
        System.setProperty("log4j.category.org.apache.shiro", "DEBUG");          
        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        String  b = "false";
        log.info("WTF");
        try{
            if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {

                UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("user1", "test")   ;
                token.setRememberMe(true);
                try {                        
                    currentUser.login(token); 
                    b = "You have successfully logged in user: " + token.getPrincipal().toString();
                    if (currentUser.hasRole("1")) {
                        b += " and they have the role of being awesome";
                    } else {
                       b += " and we can't find the role yet.";
                    }
                    
                }catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                    b =  token.getPrincipal().toString();
                    log.info("There is no user with username of " + token.getPrincipal().toString());
                } 
            }
        }catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            b = ae.toString();
            log.info(b);
        }catch(Exception e){
            b = e.toString();
            log.info(b);
        }
```

So to be clear, this currently works, because I have:

```
 currentUser.hasRole("1")
```

In there and the role field has a 1 in it for that username. If I change the 1 to "awesome" (without quotes) in both places I get the following error:

> Severe:   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Awesome' to data type int.

So how do I get it to accept strings?

My table CompanyUser:

> userid int not null auto increment
>
> personid int not null
>
> company_username varchar(15) not null
>
> company_password varchar(15) not
>
> null role varchar(20) not null

For some reason it is trying to convert the column "role" to an int.

Comment: are you sure your database column for the role field has the correct data type? maybe it was declared as int so it is trying to interpret any input as integers

Comment: For me roles with string works. Please post your table structure.

Comment: Updated question with requested information.

Comment: @dev For now I am getting it to work with the numbers, but that will only be okay for the proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `currentUser.hasRole("awesome")` not `currentUser.hasRole(awesome)`

Is awesomea a variable? If so, give example with awesome thing.

Comment: The example I gave above is the working example, where the database has a 1 variable (whether the database column is an int of varchar doesn't seem to matter. If it is a string it will work if the string is only numbers) and so does the java:  if (currentUser.hasRole("1"). Putting the role as a string is what gives me that  error, it's looking for a number for some strange reason.

Comment: For me it works with string also . I have a role "GOD" which is mapped to permission "*" and it works

Comment: can you try rolequery as SELECT CAST(role AS NVARCHAR(50)) FROM CompanyUser where company_username = ? also are you using permission as i see jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true without any permission query. make it false if you are not using. It seems it SQL Server issue of cponversion via driver It works for me with oracle.

Comment: I already tried CAST(R.role as varchar). It works, but again only with strings that can be converted to integers. I do have permissionsLookupEnabled set to true.